# Delete item from array - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I make a very simple todo list and should be next to each generated items a delete-btn.
How can I write this function via OnClick()?
i have in App.js quite normal array and now should be deleted with Delete-btn any added items.

ShowListComponent:

```
export default function ShowList ({items}){
    const isEmpty = "Die Eingabe Feld muss nicht leer sein";


    return(
        <div className='itemList'>
            {items.map((item) => (
                <ul className='itemContainer'>

                    <li className='item-name'>
                        {item.itemName}
                    </li>

                    <div className='delete-btn'>
                        <Button type="primary" danger ghost>
                            Delete
                        </Button>
                    </div>

                </ul>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

List Component:

export default function List ({items, setItems}){

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

const AddButtonClick = () => {

    if (inputValue === ""){
        alert("Eingabefeld ist Leer");
        return false
    } else {
        const newItem ={
            itemName: inputValue,
        };

        const newItems = [...items,newItem];

        setItems(newItems);
        setInputValue('');
    }

}

return(
    <>

        <Input value={inputValue} onChange={(event) =>
            setInputValue(event.target.value)}
               name='input'
               className='addItemInput'
               placeholder="Artikel hinzufügen"
        />

        <Button
            type="primary"
            className='btn'
            onClick={() => AddButtonClick()}
        >Hinzufügen</Button>

    </>
)
```

}

Comment: Are you asking how to remove an item from an array so React knows the array has been updated? How are the mechanics different from how you're already adding an item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like the `AddButtonClick()` create `deleteButtonClick`:

```
const deleteButtonClick = (index) => {
        const newItems = items && items.filter((element , i) => i !== index);
        setItems(newItems);
}
```

pass it to `ShowList` component and use it like so:

```
export default function ShowList ({items, deleteButtonClick}){
    const isEmpty = "Die Eingabe Feld muss nicht leer sein";


    return(
        <div className='itemList'>
            {items.map((item, index) => (
                <ul className='itemContainer'>

                    <li className='item-name'>
                        {item.itemName}
                    </li>

                    <div className='delete-btn'>
                        <Button type="primary" danger ghost onClick={() => deleteButtonClick(index)}>
                            Delete
                        </Button>
                    </div>

                </ul>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```